# How to get the connector talend output in bonita

Tags: talend, bonita

I'm using bonita and I would know how I can to get the talend connector output and store it.

My case is very simple, I've just a Tjava component in my talend job and the code is:

```
String foo = "bar";
System.out.printl(foo);
```

Now, how can i to get this output in bonita please?

Answer (score 0):

The output parameter of this connector can be retrieved in the last page ("Output operations") of the connector's configuration wizard.

FYI, the connector output is of type:

```
java.lang.String[][]
```

If you wish to learn more about the connector, you can have a look at its implementation here:
https://github.com/bonitasoft/bonita-connector-talend/blob/master/bonita-connector-talend-joblauncher-impl/src/main/java/org/bonitasoft/connectors/talend/JobLauncherConnector.java

Hope this helps.

POZ

Comment: Thanks. Ok its a matrix, and for example this string, I can to get it at tab[0][0] ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. It is a two dimension array.